# Как реализовать на js, jquery меню гамбургера?

Tags: javascript, jquery, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужно реализовать чтобы на мобильной версии активный пункт меню отображался рядом с иконкой гамбургера. При нажатии на этот пункт или гамбургер должен появиться весь список категорий, при выборе какой-то другой категории, список исчезает, и этот пункт становится на место старого рядом с гамбургером.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что у вас кое есть? Код, что не получается?

Comment: Чтобы при клике на гамбургер появлялся весь список категорий, я могу написать код, не знаю как сделать, чтобы потом когда пользователь выбирает и нажимает на пункт, список исчезает и этот новый пункт меню становится на место старого (рядом с гамбургером). Как на этом сайте http://musicpoint.vip, там есть кнопка "Открыть меню", именно в мобильной версии интересует

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что то вроде этого ?

```js
 $(".icon").click(function(){
     $("#myTopnav").toggleClass("responsive"); 
 });
 
 $("#myTopnav a").click(function(){
     $("#activeText").text($(this).text()); 
 });
```

```css
/* Add a black background color to the top navigation */
.topnav {
    background-color: #333;
    overflow: hidden;
}

/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
.topnav a,.topnav p {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change the color of links on hover */
.topnav a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: black;
}
.topnav p.icon{
  margin: 0px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
/* Add an active class to highlight the current page */
.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}

/* Hide the link that should open and close the topnav on small screens */
.topnav .icon {
    display: none;
}

/* When the screen is less than 600 pixels wide, hide all links, except for the first one ("Home"). Show the link that contains should open and close the topnav (.icon) */
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  .topnav p.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

/* The "responsive" class is added to the topnav with JavaScript when the user clicks on the icon. This class makes the topnav look good on small screens (display the links vertically instead of horizontally) */
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive p.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="#!" id="activeText" class="active">MENU</a>
  <a href="#!" class="">Home</a>
  <a href="#!">News</a>
  <a href="#!">Contact</a>
  <a href="#!">About</a> 
  <p class="icon">&#9776;</p>
    
</div>
```

Comment: так же можно добавить закрытие меню при выборе пункта.

Comment: Да, это именно то, что нужно, спасибо большое, тебе Даниил!